# Retrieve a specific object or array inside a Swagger definition

Tags: arrays, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Suppose I have a definition as follows:

```
definitions:
  assetList:
    type: object
    properties:
      assets:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
              description: ID
      total:
        type: integer
        description: total
```

I reference this definition across many endpoints, but there is an endpoint that responds with just the object under `assets` that has the `ID` property, and it is not in an array.

The usual way of referencing this is as a response body is `$ref: '#/definitions/assetList'`, but this includes the entire defintion. Is there any way I can reference just the object inside the `assets` array without creating an entire new definition?

Comment: Btw, the innermost `properties` keyword has wrong indentation, it should be on the same level as `type: object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can reference just the object inside the assets array without creating an entire new definition?

Not sure what you mean by "entirely new" definition here. The common solution would be to extract the object in a separate definition, and reference it from both the `assetList` and the response body:

```yaml
...
  responses:
    200:
      description: OK
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/myObject'   # <----

definitions:
  assetList:
    type: object
    properties:
      assets:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/myObject'  # <----
      total:
        type: integer
        description: total

  myObject:   # <-----
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: ID
```

If you mean you don't want to extract the inner schema, it might be possible (depending on the tool you use) to reference an inner schema directly like this:

```yaml
$ref: '#/definitions/assetList/properties/assets/items'
```

The `#/foo/bar/...` syntax is a [JSON Pointer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-04), and it allows pointing to any element in a JSON structure (or in this case, a YAML structure).

In practice, however, such references are discouraged, and some tools may not support them.